# find a way in python/pandas to cross information between couple of columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops

```
I have this database:
   id power_count  power_name  type    second_power   second_power_type
0 001 1            fire        attack  nan            nan
1 001 1            fire        attack  nan            nan
2 002 2            water       defense nan            nan
3 002 2            sand        attack  nan            nan
4 002 2            sand        attack  nan            nan
5 003 1            fire        defense nan            nan
6 004 2            fire        defense nan            nan
7 004 2            water       attack  nan            nan
```

And I want to get to this:

```
   id power_count  power_name  type    second_power   second_power_type
0 001 1            fire        attack  nan            nan
1 001 1            fire        attack  nan            nan
2 002 2            water       defense sand           attack
3 002 2            sand        attack  water          defense
4 002 2            sand        attack  water          defense
5 003 1            fire        defense nan            nan
6 004 2            fire        attack  water          attack
7 004 2            water       attack  fire           attack
```

So only in the rows that have 2 power count add the information on the other power

I tried to do a loop for doing it but didn't succeed.

Comment: Can you please post the dataframe constructor code and the code you tried?

Comment: @GiuseppeLaGualano Look at `pandas.read_clipboard` . Copy the dataframe in tabular format and call `pd.read_clipboard` to read it as DataFrame object

Comment: Thank you @ThePyGuy! @Niv Reznik if there are multiple lines like "second_power", which one do you choose? the first occurrence? In your example, when you get to the third row, there are with the same ID the fourth and the fifth.  Can you add more details for this logic?

Comment: hi! there can be only one ore two type of powers. so only in the rows with 2 types. some rows look same but there is more columns that I havent share that makes the different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a generic method based on a `merge`:

```
key = df.groupby(['id'])['power_name'].transform(lambda x: x.factorize()[0])
m = ~df[['id', 'power_name', 'type']].duplicated()

out = (df
 [['id', 'power_count', 'power_name', 'type']]
 .merge(df.loc[m, ['id', 'power_name', 'type']],
        left_on=['id', key], right_on=['id', 1-key[m]], 
        suffixes=(None ,'_2'), how='left',
         )
 .rename(columns={'power_name_2': 'second_power',
                  'type_2': 'second_power_type'})
 .drop(columns='key_1')
)
```

output:

```
   id  power_count power_name     type second_power second_power_type
0   1            1       fire   attack          NaN               NaN
1   1            1       fire   attack          NaN               NaN
2   2            2      water  defense         sand            attack
3   2            2       sand   attack        water           defense
4   2            2       sand   attack        water           defense
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {'water':'sand', 'sand':'water', 'defense':'attack', 'attack':'defense'}
df.loc[df['power_count'] == 2, ['second_power', 'second_power_type']] = df.loc[df['power_count'] == 2, ['power_name', 'type']].replace(dict1).to_numpy()
df
```

`df`

```
    id  power_count power_name  type    second_power    second_power_type
0   1   1           fire        attack  NaN             NaN
1   1   1           fire        attack  NaN             NaN
2   2   2           water       defense sand            attack
3   2   2           sand        attack  water           defense
4   2   2           sand        attack  water           defense
```

Comment: i think there is a problem with this part "df.loc[df['id'] == 2" :  there is a lot of ids and not only "2".

Comment: exchange to `powe_ count` column

Comment: In this way, the exchange is automatic for a certain type of power. But not in all cases need to switch to the same power. For example, a power type can be "water-defense" and I need it to change to "water-attack".

Comment: Solve additional situations by yourself or make new post with data of new situation.